# 35-pass erase for files; will it recover or not?

Tags: mac, security, data-recovery, secure-erase

OK, I admit it; downloaded raunchy pictures and now want to ensure they're deleted from a MacBook Pro bought in 2018 whenever I decide to gift it to someone.

Admittedly, the pictures are nothing illegal; just pictures of Holly McGuire, Jakki Degg, Samira Mighty and Georgia Toffolo.

I want to make sure they're erased and unrecoverable, in addition to ensuring sensitive files are deleted too (the files are nothing more than 2004 tax data which is backed up on a Mac mini, anyway).

In general, I've used Edenwaith permanent eraser to do the job, set it to Gutmann 35-pass.

I'm not an expert in data recovery or erasure, but will this sort of tool make sure they're unrecoverable, even after I reinstall the Macbook when giving it away as a gift?

Sure, Christmas is a long time away... but I want to do this right.

Comment: The only way to be certain is to destroy the storage device and install a new one that hasn't yet been sullied. However, anything beyond a few writes and overwrites is going to require some intense effort and sophisticated equipment to recover, so, you're LIKELY to be OK. Also, this question is answered a thousand times and a thousand times again all over the internet. You should have searched, which is one reason why this was closed and isn't likely to be reopened.

Comment: Generally only 1-2 passes are required to make data unreadable. the Guttman paper that the 35-pass  recommendation is based on is about EM fields in theoretical circumstances, and doesn't match the realities of the situation. the bigger concern is caches and indexes and journals and whatnot, so slick the whole disk with dban before you rebuild it.

Comment: I really hope is wasn't an SSD you subjected to that kind of overkill erase. Multi-pass erase does nothing on an SSD except wear it out rapidly. For a Mac, if you have FileVault on, then any data erased is as gone as gone can be. When you pass the machine on, just remove the filevault as part of the standard procedure & everything ever on there is gone far beyond recovery.